# Converting monthly values into daily using pandas interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have 12 avg monthly values for 1000 columns and I want to convert the data into daily using pandas. I have tried to do it using *interplolate* but I got the daily values from 31/01/1991 to 31/12/1991, which does not cover the whole year. January month values are not getting. I used *date_range* for index of my data frame.

```
date=pd.date_range(start="01/01/1991",end="31/12/1991",freq="M")

upsampled=df.resample("D")
interpolated = upsampled.interpolate(method='linear')
```

How can I get the interpolated values for 365 days?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that interpolation is **between** the known points.

So to interpolate throughout the whole year, it is not enough to have
just **12** values (for each month).
You must have **13** values (e.g. for the start of each month **and**
the start of the next year).

Thus I created the source *df* as:

```
date = pd.date_range(start='01/01/1991', periods=13, freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'amount': np.random.randint(100, 200, date.size)})
```

getting e.g.:

```
         date  amount
0  1991-01-01     113
1  1991-02-01     164
2  1991-03-01     181
3  1991-04-01     164
4  1991-05-01     155
5  1991-06-01     157
6  1991-07-01     118
7  1991-08-01     133
8  1991-09-01     184
9  1991-10-01     183
10 1991-11-01     159
11 1991-12-01     193
12 1992-01-01     163
```

​Then to upsample it to daily frequency and interpolate, I ran:

```
df.set_index('date').resample('D').interpolate()
```

If you don't want the result to contain the last row (for *1992-01-01*),
take only a slice of the above result, dropping the last row:

```
df.set_index('date').resample('D').interpolate()[:-1]
```