# Break up monthly data into daily values

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe with multiple columns that contain aggregate values per month.

I would like to break up the monthly aggregates into daily ones.

The original dataframe looks like this:

```
​
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
                        'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                        'col_A': np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=12),
                        'col_B': np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=12)})
print(df)

        month      col_A      col_B
0     January        102        330
1    February        435        458
2       March        860         87
3       April        270        372
4         May        106         99
5        June         71        871
6        July        700        663
7      August         20        130
8   September        614        661
9     October        121        308
10   November        466        769
11   December        214        343
```

My aim is to convert the monthly aggregates to a daily view that looks like this for the whole year:

```
        date      col_A      col_B
0 2022-01-01   3.290323  10.645161
1 2022-01-02   3.290323  10.645161
2 2022-01-03   3.290323  10.645161
3 2022-01-04   3.290323  10.645161
4 2022-01-05   3.290323  10.645161
```

I converted the month to a datetime object and added

`df['month'] = df.month.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%B") + relativedelta(years = 122))`

Then I tried to interpolate with resampling as suggested below, however, the results I get are not the same as well as it interpolates between the points instead of dividing the values with the number of days in a month.

[Converting monthly values into daily using pandas interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61095654/converting-monthly-values-into-daily-using-pandas-interpolatio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First generate the dates for each month, assuming in year 2022.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'] + ' 2022')\
    .apply(pd.date_range, freq='MS', periods=2)\
    .apply(lambda ds: pd.date_range(*ds, closed='left'))
```

Second divide the values by number of days per month

```
df['col_A'] /= df['date'].apply(len)
df['col_B'] /= df['date'].apply(len)
```

Explode the dates column and the divided values get copied.

```
df.explode('date')
```